# How to determine which player it will start by sending a Virtual-Key VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT

Tags: winapi, vbscript, media-player, sendkeys, keyboard-input

Under Win2K(or later), by sending a Virtual-Key VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT, can start a player.

If more than one player software installed, how to determine which one it will start?

A sample VBS code:

```
Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Sendkeys chr(&h88b5)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/dd375731

```
VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT
0xB5
Select Media key
```

Answer (score 1):

`VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT` is actually received by the system and translated into a `WM_APPCOMMAND` with `lParam` as `APPCOMMAND_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT`. So theoretically, any program implementing a handler for this could be launched. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463446.aspx#EZJAC) (albeit old) lists default applications which listen for `WM_APPCOMMAND`:

- Internet Explorer
- Windows Help
- DVD Player
- CD Player
- Media Player
- Volume Control system tray applet

Obviously, only a few of those are actually applicable for `APPCOMMAND_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT`.

However, I don't know how the translation mechanism actually works. It appears not every application will receive the translated `WM_APPCOMMAND` message. On my keyboard, I tried pressing the button which sends `VK_VOLUME_UP`. The volume goes up as expected because it is handled by the volume control system tray applet. However, I opened an instance of `notepad.exe` and monitored its messages with Spy++. It did not receive any message even when it was in the foreground. Curiously, `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` is received through `WM_APPCOMMAND` if the play/pause button is pressed as long as `notepad.exe` had the focus. I would test with `VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT`, but I'm not actually sure what button that corresponds to (or whether my keyboard has it).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. On my testing, sending the Virtual-Key VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT is by VBS: Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Sendkeys chr(&h88b5)                                Set the default association for the CDA (CD Audio) files to Notepad or Paint or any other program, it can still send the same virtual key to open the corresponding program.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, for Mike Kwan's reply.

Through testing a lot of settings a program associated with a variety of audio files.
Finalized, this will depend on the **CDA (CD Audio)** files **associated with which program**.

If you set the default association for the CDA (CD Audio) files to Notepad or Paint or **any** other **program**, it can still send the same virtual key to open the corresponding program.

Answer (score 1):

The foreground window can do whatever it wants in response to the [WM_APPCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, if it does not handle the message then shell hooks (HSHELL_APPCOMMAND) gets to handle it, if no hooks handle the message then Windows checks the [AppKey](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/6232.aspx#120) key in the registry. (You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find the number for a specific key-press)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! For these you said, I also need some learning.